# JBOSS App Server vs. Glassfish

Tags: jboss, glassfish, application-server

I'm quite newbie on Glassfish.

What are some differences between JBoss and Glassfish?
Why would you chooose one over the other.

I'm trying to read up on Glassfish, but it is really hard to pinpoint things that I may need before I start installing and trying to deploy some applications on it.

**UPDATE**
It would be good if any additional information on JBoss and Glassfish comparison is provided
(e.g. technologies they support, performance, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

We have studied relative performance of JBoss vs. Glassfish, and found that Glassfish scales much better under high loads.

Comment: JBoss is using Tomcat with defaults to thread based scaling. Glassfish uses Grizzly which defaults to NIO based scaling.

Comment: And the threads-based scaling was really the problem. All kinds of things start to break under load.

Answer (score 5):

you may want to try your questions over at stackoverflow.com.  At my company the programming teams set up those application servers and then work with production support.  We keep JBoss in our repository because of all the configuration changes and each server we deploy needs to be slightly modified.

I've enjoyed playing with JBoss and the people in the forums are pretty active, but I haven't worked with Glassfish so I can't give any comparisons, but a search returned :

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glassfish+jboss

Because I'm a new user I can't post all three links that I wanted to from that search, but there are several good answers from the search above.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss has maturity, whereas Glassfish is striving to be **THE** reference J2EE stack.  A year from now, there'll be almost no difference to your production deployments.

Comment: Glassfish starts instantly, JBoss takes a bit.

Comment: Starting time shouldn't be a real issues in a production environment surely?

Comment: Absolutely.  As more and more vendors are creating Hypervisor-based JVMs to support lightweight VMs, there's going to be growing emphasis on all aspects of performance.  Expect that as "cloud" progresses forward, this becomes more and more important for on-demand delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the features difference between Glassfish and Jboss published by Oracle. Straight from the horses mouth.

[Comparing Oracle GlassFish Server and JBoss: Which Application Server Is Right for You?](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/oracle-glassfish-server/comparing-glassfish-jboss-wp-117118.pdf) [PDF]

Comment: And of course Oracle isn't at all biased.